# Descripcion de metodos

Tags: visual-studio-2017

¿Como hago en el visual studio para que me aparezca la descripción de un método que haya creado?

un ejemplo así como esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que documentar el método en c# y tiene su sintaxis, es en xml. Debes agregar unos comentarios antes del método para que lo reconozca, como si se tratase de un javadoc. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Descripción
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="param1">Algún parámetro</param>
    /// <returns>Aquí pones lo que retorna el método</returns>
```

Sin embargo, Visual Studio cuenta con una [herramienta](https://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) que te permite generar documentación para tus métodos en c#.